# Static Lib To Help With Dll Plugins In C++

Tags: c++, dll, plugins, directx

I'm an indie game developer, who previously focused on XNA. Currently I'm making the transition to native C++ and DX10. My latest project is an RPG and I have finished an early alpha version, but I want to do a complete rewrite for my next version (following the "make it work, make it clean, make it fast" principle).

Given the nature of the game, I'm currently trying to implement a "Game Act" plugin system (1st Act = Tutorial, 2nd Act = home village...) using Dlls, similar to the approach used [here](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Adding_Plug-ins_To_Your_Application.shtml). However, as I'm still fairly new to C++ I haven't worked with Dlls before. I've read a number of tutorials (I'm using the third approach outlined [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/howto_export_cpp_classes.aspx)) and my system is currently working quite well. My question now is: if I want to make my game available to the modding community, how should I make the abstract base classes used by my Dll available to them? Should I place them in a separate static library that the Dll project uses as well? Or is there a better approach? I think this could work quite well, but I'm concerned about versioning issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I would go with the static lib.

As for versioning, while you cannot version the lib itself you can solve this by simply hosting your lib in a public source repository and naming it with the version number matching the current version of your gaming engine.